# MapComposer not found Error

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, grids-graticules

I was working on an example provided in the  [pyqgis developer cookbook](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/index.html)  and performed the code in the QGIS version 2.8.9 but i am getting the following error:

**ImportError: No module named MapComposer**

I had tried the link provided in the book but that is not working.

My code is as follows:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
import MapComposer

lyr = QgsVectorLayer("/qgis_data/ms/mmississippi.shp",
"Mississippi", "ogr")
reg = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance()
reg.addMapLayer(lyr)
mr = iface.mapCanvas().mapRenderer()
qc = MapComposer.MapComposer(qmlr=reg, qmr=mr)

setGridAnnoPos = qc.composerMap.setGridAnnotationPosition
setGridAnnoDir = qc.composerMap.setGridAnnotationDirection
qcm = QgsComposerMap

qc.composerMap.setGridEnabled(True)
qc.composerMap.setGridIntervalX(.75)
qc.composerMap.setGridIntervalY(.75)
qc.composerMap.setGridStyle(qcm.Solid)

qc.composerMap.setShowGridAnnotation(True)
qc.composerMap.setGridAnnotationPrecision(0)

setGridAnnoPos(qcm.OutsideMapFrame, qcm.Top)
setGridAnnoDir(qcm.Horizontal, qcm.Top)
setGridAnnoPos(qcm.OutsideMapFrame, qcm.Bottom)
setGridAnnoDir(qcm.Horizontal, qcm.Bottom)
setGridAnnoPos(qcm.OutsideMapFrame, qcm.Left)
setGridAnnoDir(qcm.Vertical, qcm.Left)
setGridAnnoPos(qcm.OutsideMapFrame, qcm.Right)
setGridAnnoDir(qcm.Vertical, qcm.Right)

qc.composerMap.setAnnotationFrameDistance(1)
qc.composerMap.setGridPenWidth(.2)
qc.composerMap.setGridPenColor(QColor(0, 0, 0))
qc.composerMap.setAnnotationFontColor(QColor(0, 0, 0))
qc.c.addComposerMap(qc.composerMap)

qc.output("/qgis_data/map.jpg", "jpg")
```

Comment: Have you checked this question: [Creating new print composer programmatically? [closed](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/246027/creating-new-print-composer-programmatically/246149)

Comment: There is nothing related to MapComposer library. Actually i am looking for this library. and that example is more over dedicated to set page size

Comment: You may look at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/190165/module-map-composer-not-found for a clue. In my opinion, you are trying to mix too many samples code inherited from multiple PyQGIS versions associated with corresponding QGIS versions. For specific doc for QGIS 2.8, look at the API docs e.g https://qgis.org/api/2.8/annotated.html Not sure why you need a so old version of QGIS (2.8 released in february 2015 FYI)

Comment: I am using this code because i am new to python don't know how to write codes on my own so i was using this code to make grid on the vector file which i had. 
I don,t know how to make grid using QGIS 3.10 if you know how to write a python code for making grid in a vector file then please help